# How can random string look like slot machine

Tags: java, android, string, random, audio

In my program, I have only 1 button. And first press the program will output a random string. If the user presses it again to stop, my program will slow random (delay) the same slot machine. How can I do it?

my code

```
package com.Randomsentence;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Randomsentence extends Activity {

    boolean showRandom = false;
    TextView txt;
    int time = 30;
    int random;
    public String[] myString;
    Button bt1;
    boolean check = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Medaiplayer mp = new Medaiplayer();
        Mediaplayer mp2 = new Mediaplayer();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.AudioFile1);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.AudioFile2);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showRandom = !showRandom;
                t = new Thread() {

                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (showRandom) {
                                mp.start();
                                mp2.reset();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                sleep(1000);
                                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                            }
                            mp.reset();
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp2.start();

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
    // our handler
    Handler handler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {//display each item in a single line
            {
                Random rgenerator = new Random();
                Resources res = getResources();
                myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
                String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                txt.setText(q);

            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `slow random (delay) the same lottery` does not make sense.

Comment: It mean when i press button again string don't stop Immediately. but it will slow to stop similar lottory

Comment: What do you mean by "lottery"?  As far as I can tell from code, this is nothing to do with lotteries.

Comment: Looks like the code from your question about looping sound, that i just answered! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481798/how-to-loop-sound-in-android/6481836#6481836

Comment: Maybe "lottery" means a slot machine/poker machine? @user814154: You can edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the MediaPlayer part, I think it should be this way:

```
package com.Randomsentence;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Randomsentence.R;

public class Randomsentence extends Activity {
    TextView txt;
    int random;
    public String[] myStrings;
    Button bt1;

    private static final int MESSAGE_RANDOM = 1;
    private static final long MIN_INTERVAL = 500;
    private static final long MAX_INTERVAL = 1500;
    private static final long STEP = 60;

    private long mInterval = 0;
    private boolean mStarted = false;

    private Random mRandom = new Random();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == MESSAGE_RANDOM) {
                showRandomString();
                if(mStarted) {
                    this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_RANDOM, mInterval);
                } else {
                    if(mInterval <= MAX_INTERVAL) {
                        this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_RANDOM, mInterval);
                        mInterval += STEP;
                    } else {
                        this.removeMessages(MESSAGE_RANDOM);
                        Toast.makeText(Randomsentence.this, "Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(mBt1OnClick);
        myStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
    }

    private void showRandomString() {
        final int index = mRandom.nextInt(myStrings.length - 1);
        txt.setText(myStrings[index]);
    }

    private OnClickListener mBt1OnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mStarted) {
                // Start
                Toast.makeText(Randomsentence.this, "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mStarted = true;
                mInterval = MIN_INTERVAL;
                mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_RANDOM);
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_RANDOM);
            } else {
                // Stop
                mStarted = false;
                Toast.makeText(Randomsentence.this, "Stoping...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: But i want sound too. When first press button sound will active , and when second press button another sound will active.How i can add it

Comment: Just replace the 2 Toasts in onClick to your MediaPlayer thing.